# How to switch Views in tabbed app on iOS6?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say you have a project that you started as a "Tabbed Application", which creates two tabbed Views by default. Now, you have another NIB that is separate from these Tabs (that is, you don't want it to be a part of tab items, and you have it as a separate set of .m, .h, .xib files).

How do you bring this View to the front? And then how do you hide it?

Comment: Tabbed application doesn't create two views only, it creates two `UIVIewControllers` that are being managed by `UITabBarController`

Answer (score 1):

Use the function called bringSubviewToFront

Example: `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:newView];`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another view to UIViewController:

Files: `View.h`, `View.m`, `View.xib`

In View.h:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *customView;
```

In View.m:

```
#import "View.h"

- (void)addSubView
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:nil options:nil];
    self.customView = nib[0];
    [self.view addSubview:self.customView];
}

- (void)removeSubView
{
    [self.customView removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: Functional, but with 3 anti-patterns in one code snippet: (1) using an `enum` simply to define an integer constant, (2) using a tag, when simply saving the new view in an ivar/property will do, and (3) naming a local variable (`view`) the same as a class property.